# get last data from foreach object data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

how to get last data from foreach , i want to save for last data to result ,

image for result :

**Result**

[image]

```
<?php
$s_kredit   = 0;
foreach ($ju as $j ) {
                $s_debet += $j->debet   - $j->kredit;
                $s_kredit += $j->kredit - $j->debet;
<tr>
<td class="center"><?php if(@$set_saldo->debet==0) { echo "-"; } else { echo number_format($s_debet,0,".","."); } ;?></td>
<td class="center"><?php if(@$set_saldo->kredit==0) { echo "-"; } else { echo number_format($s_kredit,0,".","."); } ;?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: You have provide current and desire result.

Comment: please answers for this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
$data=array(1,3,4,5,6,7,7);
$last = $data[count($data) - 1]; 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [end](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) function.

> end — Set the internal pointer of an array to its last element

```
$array=[3,4,5,8];    
echo end($array); // 8
```

Comment: $last_record=$ju[count($ju)-1];

Comment: @RockersTechnology: end function is a good option to retrieve last index value of an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// ok try it nothing else, every loop change $last value, & when loop end, last variable will stored in the $last. 
$s_kredit   = 0;
$last = '';
foreach ($ju as $j ) {
            $s_debet += $j->debet   - $j->kredit;
            $s_kredit += $j->kredit - $j->debet;
            $last = $j;
<tr>
<td class="center"><?php if(@$set_saldo->debet==0) { echo "-"; } else { echo    number_format($s_debet,0,".","."); } ;?></td>
<td class="center"><?php if(@$set_saldo->kredit==0) { echo "-"; } else {    echo number_format($s_kredit,0,".","."); } ;?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: no , Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string,,

i want to end result is 1.500.000 bro ,

Comment: see edited code

Answer (score 0):

Create another variable

```
<?php
$s_kredit   = 0;
$s_final   = 0;
foreach ($ju as $j ) {
                $s_debet += $j->debet   - $j->kredit;
                $s_kredit += $j->kredit - $j->debet;
                $s_final = $j->kredit;
<tr>
<td class="center"><?php if(@$set_saldo->debet==0) { echo "-"; } else { echo number_format($s_debet,0,".","."); } ;?></td>
<td class="center"><?php if(@$set_saldo->kredit==0) { echo "-"; } else { echo number_format($s_kredit,0,".","."); } ;?></td>
</tr>
}

// show $s_final after the loop
```